# iOS9で位置情報を使う定期バックグラウンド処理が止まる

Tags: swift

iOS9で位置情報を使う定期バックグラウンド処理を行い、自分の位置情報をサーバに情報をアップロードしようとしています。3点問題・疑問点があります。

1. 位置情報更新の定期バックグランド処理がいつからか止まる原因は？（いつから何がきっかけで止まっているのか不明）
2. AppDelegateのSingletonを使えばというコメントをいただいたが、位置情報定期バックグランド処理がいつからか止まる原因がSingletonを使っていないことに起因するのか不明。
3. そもそも位置情報定期バッググランド処理のSingleton化のやり方がわかりません。
   　func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation){}
   のSingleton?コード方法がわかりません。

参考までに私が書いたプログラムを添付しておきます。必要がないと思われる関数などは適当に削除しています。
すべての疑問に一度の回答でなくてもかまいません。部分的にもご存知の方、何卒ご教示お願いします。

<追記ですが、バックグランドで動かすために設定(+位置情報を使うための)した内容です>
・CapabilityesのBackground ModesでLocation updatesをチェック
・info.plistに
　NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescriptionの設定
　Required background modes -> Item 0 でApp registers for location updatesを設定
・CoreLocation.frameworkをインポート

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    var keido: String!
    var ido:String!    
    var lm: CLLocationManager! = nil
    var longitude: CLLocationDegrees!
    var latitude: CLLocationDegrees!

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        longitude = CLLocationDegrees()
        latitude = CLLocationDegrees()
        keido = String(stringInterpolationSegment: longitude)
        ido = String(stringInterpolationSegment: latitude)

        lm = CLLocationManager()
        lm.delegate = self
        lm.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        lm.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters // 100m
        lm.distanceFilter = 100.0 // 100m移動したら位置情報更新
        lm.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false // 更新頻度が低いと止まることを抑制(false)
        lm.startUpdatingLocation()
        return true
    }

    // 位置情報アップデート
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation){
        longitude = newLocation.coordinate.longitude
        latitude = newLocation.coordinate.latitude
        keido = String(stringInterpolationSegment: longitude)
        ido = String(stringInterpolationSegment: latitude)
        let myUrl:NSURL = NSURL(string: NSString(format:"http://(*mask*)/location/locationget.php?id=(mask)&longitude=%@&latitude=%@",String(stringInterpolationSegment: longitude),String(stringInterpolationSegment: latitude)) as String)!
        let myRequest:NSURLRequest  = NSURLRequest(URL: myUrl)
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(myRequest, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: self.getHttp)
    }

    func getHttp(res:NSURLResponse?,data:NSData?,error:NSError?){
        // 帰ってきたデータを文字列に変換.
        let myData:NSString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        NSLog(myData as String)
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError){
        NSLog("Error")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

解決につながるかどうかわかりませんが、部分的にもということなので、回答の形で書かせていただきます。

*1. 位置情報更新の定期バックグランド処理がいつからか止まる原因は？（いつから何がきっかけで止まっているのか不明）*
様々な要因で位置情報更新の通知は停止します。詳しくはできるだけ公式のドキュメントを当たって調べてください。
[位置情報とマップ プログラミングガイド](https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/LocationAwarenessPG.pdf)
[Location and Maps Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)
(日本語版のタイムスタンプはかなり古いので、できれば英語版を当たってください。)
[iOSアプリケーション プログラミングガイド](https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/iPhoneAppProgrammingGuide.pdf)
[App Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)
(「バックグラウンド実行」に関して独立した章で説明されており、「ユーザの位置情報の追跡」についても説明されています。その他の章にも関連事項が記載されています。)

詳細なチェックリストは持ち合わせていないので、ざっくりとした記述になりますが、

- バックグラウンドのアプリケーションはいつでもシステムから停止させられる可能性がある
  (標準位置情報サービスでは停止しているアプリケーションの起動まではやってくれません。)
- 必要な宣言をしていれば、簡単には停止しないはずなので各種の設定を再度見直す必要がある
- NSURLConnectionはバックグラウンドでの動作は保証されていない

と言ったところでしょうか。

2.と3.については、Singleton化とバックグラウンド実行については全く関係がないので、あなたが根拠にされているコメントの前後の文脈を示していただかないと、なんとも言えません。

Comment: 「必要な宣言をしていれば、簡単には停止しないはずなので各種の設定を再度見直す必要がある」の必要な宣言が明記されているページ or 情報を知りたいです。"絶対に停止しない"は必要ありませんが"簡単に停止しない"はやっておきたいと思っています。内容が位置情報の精度を甘くすればということであればそれも受け入れられます。ご教示お願いします。

Comment: リンク先に記載されておりますのが私の知っているすべてです。内容をご確認ください。

Comment: 一応、設定系は見ましたが、必要な宣言はしています（多分）。Background Fetch をアプリに組み込んでおいて、発動したらstartUpdateLocationを叩くというというワークアラウンドもあるようなので、これを試してみたいと思います。他に情報があればお願いします。

Comment: あまりお役には立てなかったようですが、このような設定はしました、というのも含めてご質問内容を編集されましたら、他に経験のある方のアドバイスが得られるかもしれません。